# Limit a range PHP SQL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Two parts to this question, I currently have a php script which grabs new info from themoviedb, however it times out so I'm trying to limit it in order to chunk it. I have this below snippet.

```
$Posts = $this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->all();
```

I am trying to limit it to 250 results as opposed to all, I have tried.

```
$Posts = $this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->limit(250);
$Posts = $this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->limit('250');
```

However these don't work, is anyone able to help ?

Also I was looking to see if it's possible to limit a range of results as opposed to a quantity such as limiting to 251 - 500 ?

```
$Posts = $this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->limit('1','250');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have attached a pastebin of the full code.

https://pastebin.com/C3DgFQik

Solution found:

```
$Posts = $this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->limit(0,0)->all();
```

Using `limit` you can set both `offset` and the `limit` of results, the first `0` is the offset and the second `0` is the `limit`.

```
$Posts = $this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->limit(10,5)->all();
```

This would retrieve results 11 - 15.

Comment: I see no SQL above. Perhaps you should consider another tag?

Comment: Apologies it was recommended, however I'm sure this is SQL as it's grabbing information from the database from table posts where type is series ?

Comment: Which Framework are you using ?

Comment: SQL looks something like `SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE type = 123 LIMIT 250`.

Comment: I'm not sure on the framework it's just a php script I had downloaded and installed on server, I'm usually quite competent at modifying and fixing php but this formatting is new to me.

Comment: I have attached a pastebin of the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditedSo if I am correct you are using Codeigniter , and in that you can use the Limit but after that, you need to use get also like this,

```
$this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->limit($limit,$start)->get();
```

Comment: This returns a 500 error: $this->db->from('posts')->where('type','serie')->limit(5)->get();
however reverting back to my original line resolves the error.

https://remotestre.am/api/tmdb/auto

Comment: is this laravel framework or anything else?

Comment: It was a prewritten script, I honestly don't know. I have attached a pastebin of the full code though.

Answer (score 0):

Would have been cool to know from which library come those function

```
from()
where()
all()
```

If you tell me from where your function come, i will update my answer

But to help you find a way , In pure sql language

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type = "serie" LIMIT 250
```

So bases on your code i dont see a "logic" mistake, so its probably link the function `limit()` itself

To get a proper range, from 251 to - 500 just add an OFFSET

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type = "serie" LIMIT 250 OFFSET 251
```

For exemple, for 751 to 1000

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type = "serie" LIMIT 250 OFFSET 751
```